# How to use the Hadoop api to determine if a file is empty?

Tags: hadoop

Note that it is judged whether the file is empty, that is, only the file exists, there is no content in the file, not the folder is empty.
How can I do it ? Is this ok ?

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(URI), super.getConf(), "hadoop");
FSDataOutputStream append = fs.append(new Path("path"));
System.out.println(append.size() == 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending to approach, you can do it as below:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(URI), super.getConf(), "hadoop");
```

Check if dir is empty. See API [doc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/index.html)

```
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> files = fs.listFiles(<path-to-dir>, true)
// from iterator, determine if dir is empty

FileStatus[] files = fs.listStatus(<path-to-dir>)
// use array length to determine if dir is empty
// This also throws FileNotFoundException if file/dir does not exist, you can use it to determine if dir/file does not exist
```

Check if file is empty. See API doc [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/index.html) and [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html)

```
long length = fs.getFileStatus(<file-path>).getLen()
// based on length determine if file is empty
```